# initialize a class without copy construct

Tags: c++

I'm reading a chapter in c++ priemr about copy construct,the book says “During copy initialization, the compiler is permitted (but not obligated) to skip the copy/move constructor and create the object directly. That is, the compiler is permitted to rewrite

```
string null_book="xxxxxxx";
```

into

```
string null_book("xxxxxxx");
```

even if the compiler omits the call to the copy/move constructor, the copy/move constructor must exist and must be accessible"

then i write a class and delete copy constructor

```
class myclass {
public:
myclass(int a):id(a){
    std::cout << "construct: "<<id<<std::endl;
}
myclass(const myclass& s) = delete; 
myclass& operator=(const myclass& s) = delete;
private:
int id=0 ;
};
```

if i do this it compiled successfully

```
 myclass c = 2;
```

but this gives me error

```
myclass c =myclass(2);
```

i'm totally confused, please help me,thanks a alot

Comment: Before C++17 both should give an error.

Comment: Can't reproduce with [c++17](https://wandbox.org/permlink/94qDcxIhk57pwvcZ), what's your compiler?

Comment: i use visual studio 2017

Comment: i changed the c++ standard in vs2017 to c++17, both works without error

Comment: Yes, both should work because of *guaranteed copy elision* introduced from c++17.

Comment: so  myclass c=2  still use the copy construct right?

Comment: @zxy1122 Before C++17, yes; since C++17, no.

Comment: so if it use copy constructor before c++17 and i delete it as you see,why it can compile without error,i really dont understand

Comment: @zxy1122 I guess it's bug of msvc, [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/A35GTbCKUflpy6WB) works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> myclass c = expr;
> ```

is copy initialisation. Before C++17, for this to be well-formed, the type must be copyable or at least movable.

Since C++17, the expression that is used to initialise the temporary (in first case, there is implicit conversion from int that produces the temporary) is used to initialise `c` instead, so there is no copy/move involved and the program is well-formed in the latest standard.

Answer (score 1):

## before C++17

Move constructor is required.

## Since C++17

C++ compiler must do RVO(Return Value Optimization) so that move constructor is now not required.

[P0135R1 Wording for guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html)